# I need the navbar opens to the right

Tags: asp.net, navbar

I need a slide-bar that opens to the right. I want to do this with nav-bar of bootrstrap 4.

Currently The nav-bar opens to down.

I dont want to position it to the right, i want to open it to right.

thannks

```
<div class="pos-f-t">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark col-2">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </nav>
    <div class="collapse col-2" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <nav class="navbar-nav ml-auto bg-light">
            <!-- Links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tnewxb5j/2/)?

Comment: No, i just do it with this: [link](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/simple-sidebar/)